# how to debug view in rails slim framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I want to debug my view in rails slim framework.

In my html.erb file i can do this

```
<%= debug @current_user %>
```

How do i do this in rails html.slim file?

i tried doing

```
- if current_user.has_role?(:student) || current_user.has_role?(:teacher)
    .home-header-box.center
        h3.welcome-header-title
            LP Welcome to TeachForMe

debug current_user
```

but it isnt working.

Any help appreciated

Comment: I am not familiar with slim, but judging from the code and their documentation, would it not simply be `== debug @current_user` (or something to that effect)?

Answer (score 6):

To run Ruby code in Slim template you just need to use `=` sign

`= debug @current_user`